# How to sign Delphi application on macOS under ssh session from windows machine?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, codesign

I am building Delphi firemonkey application on Windows for macOS and deploying on macOS. Now to publish the app, I need to codesign it under macOS.

I would like to ssh from Windows machine under macOS as the part of shell script and codesign mac build and publish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this just by moving codesigning certificate from the login keychain to the system keychain. Before that the codesigning script was running only under terminal on macOS, not through ssh session.

Now I can build and publish macOS app on Windows - compile, deploy, codesign and copy to a webserver.

Comment: Good to know that you found a solution. I am currently running a shell script manually on the Mac after deploying the app, but it would be even greater if Delphi supported an automatic execution of a post-deploy shellscript.